# C++ VS Express 2010 Intellisense

Tags: c++, intellisense

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Express 2010 to write an openGL program, so It's a win32 console application. And I can't get Intellisense to show up for anything, openGL or otherwise.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I force Intellisense to show? (Like you can force the Xcode equivalent with Esc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:
IntelliSense can stop working under certain conditions. Use the following steps to help determine why IntelliSense does not work for C++ projects.

To investigate IntelliSense failure in C++ projects
Make sure that the Visual C++ project contains no compilation errors.

1) If the project is a Makefile project, see How to: Enable IntelliSense for Makefile Projects.

2) Make sure that stdafx.h is on the include path. For more information about include paths in Visual C++ projects, see #include Directive (C/C++) and /I (Additional Include Directories).

Also :*General, All Languages, Text Editor, Options Dialog Box

Provides information about how to turn off IntelliSense.

NB.
IntelliSense LimitationsIntelliSense does not work in C++ projects under the following circumstances: ( there more then this one below )

IntelliSense is not fully supported when you reference a header file multiple times by using the #include directive, and the meaning of that header file changes because of various macro states that are defined through the #define directive. In other words, when you include a header file several times and the header usage changes under different macro states, IntelliSense does not always work.

Comment: In the end I just have to press Ctrl+J to force it up. I wish there was some macro or something which kept it permanently open.

Answer (score 1):

Please find *.sdf file in project directory and delete it relaunch the solution file. It will show your intellisense